# Simplify equation using conditions/inequalities

Tags: equation-solving

If I have an equation like

```
f[x](1 + a)==0
```

I'd like to be able to tell Mathematica that 1+a doesn't vanish in general, and get back

```
f[x]==0
```

I've come up with

```
Reduce[f[x](1 + a)==0 && (1 + a) != 0, f[t]][[1]]
```

But it's not clear to me this is the best solution.

EDIT: The reason this isn't ideal to me is that it seems sometimes the part that I want isn't always the first part of the output, so it doesn't generalize well. Sometimes I need to take [[1]], other times [[3]], etc.

Comment: Not sure if I get Your question correctly, does `Simplify[f[x] (1 + a) == 0, (1 + a)! == 0]` works the way You want?

Comment: Can you provide a working example that represents the behavior described in the edit?

Comment: Hi Wojciech, that works. Thank you for putting up with my lack of expertise!

Comment: @ Wojciech Can you formulate your comment in the form of an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty straightforward, but I decided to post it anyway. The solution is to use function `Simplify[exp,assum]`, with suitable assumptions. It works for an equation with just two factors as well as with more complex equations consisting of more factors.

```
Simplify[f[x] (1 + a) (1 + b)== 0, (1 + a)! = 0]
```

> (1 + b) f[x] == 0

If You want to specify that more than one factor is unequal to 0 then

```
Simplify[f[x] (1 + a) (1 + b) == 0, {(1 + a) != 0, (1 + b) != 0}]
```

> f[x] == 0

Comment: FullSimplify seems to work the same way, is there a reason to prefer Simplify over FullSimplify?

Comment: `FullSimplify` attempts to perform much more transformations than `Simplify`, but I don't think there's such a reason in Your case, apart from timing (10^-17 for `Simplify`, 0.031 for `FullSimplify` on my machine).

Comment: @Adam if this answer solves Your problem, You can accept it by clicking the tick. Now I'm officially a rep b****.

Comment: Thanks Wojciech. I'm new to this site - I tried to upvote you hours ago but couldn't (need more rep), and didn't notice the check :)

Comment: @Adam Thanks and good luck on Your _Mathematica_ adventure!